# What is dxGDIPlusClasses.dcu ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

A few month a go i wrote a program, now when i try to compile it i receive this error :

> [DCC Fatal Error] PVCM.dpr(7): F1026
>   File not found: 'dxGDIPlusClasses.dcu'

I don't know which component I've used .

Comment: IN future, general technique is to search your hard drive for this unit (use .pas not .dcu for extension).

Comment: I did. but the DevExpress package was an executable file

Comment: First link in Google points to devexpress forums

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a Devexpress component for GDI+. Devexpress units invariably have `cx` or `dx` prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a DevExpress component.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem right now !!!

Go to the unit that generates the error. Look at the top of its source code.

You will find under Uses a unit called: dxGDIPlusClasses. Remove it and you should be fine.

Hint: Next time when you remove a set of components. You have to update the USES block in your previous projects or at least, give'em a double check.